# bsModal works with fluidPage but not without it

Tags: r, shiny, shinybs

I found the **bsModal** works as expected with *fluidPage* but not without it. Just click "View Table" button to see the difference.

The version with *fluidPage*:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

shinyApp(
  ui =
    fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          actionButton("tabBut", "View Table")
        ),

        mainPanel(
          bsModal("modalExample", "Data Table", "tabBut", size = "large",
                  "distTable")
        )
      )
    ),
  server =
    function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

The version without *fluidPage*, the only change is that the *fluidPage* is replaced by tagList:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

shinyApp(
  ui =
    tagList(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          actionButton("tabBut", "View Table")
        ),

        mainPanel(
          bsModal("modalExample", "Data Table", "tabBut", size = "large",
                  "distTable")
        )
      )
    ),
  server =
    function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

Can anyboday help me explain what happened between **bsModal** and **fluidPage**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `fluidPage` is much, much more than a simple `tagList`.

`tagList` simply takes it arguments and concatenates them (expecting each argument to be some sort of HTML tag). `fluidPage` literally generates an entire HTML document with bootstrap dependencies.

Your first example is figuratively "build a house with basement, floor plan and attic" with `sidebarLayout` explaining the layout of floors and `fluidPage` being the house. Remove the `fluidPage` and you're trying to build a house with basement, floor plan and attic, but without the foundation, walls or roof.

Comment: Does it mean fluidPage will load all bsModal's dependencies? Would like to know what's the specific dependency?

Comment: `fluidPage` does not know of its childrens' dependencies, so it does not load `bsModal`s. `bsModal` loads its own dependencies. Try typing in the R console `fluidPage`, `tagList` and `bsModal`, without parenthesis, to view their definitions and look for `attachDependencies`. For some of the functions you might have to look up the function they are calling to elude their inner workings.